# <br> not getting replaced

Tags: php, wordpress

I have function like below to add new line if there is a 
 exist in my string.

```
function add_new_line($content)
{
    return str_replace("<br>","<br clear='none'/>", $content);
}

add_filter('plugin_title', 'add_new_line');
```

From my page, I am calling `echo apply_filters('plugin_title', get_the_content());` but looks like it is not working. But If I replace `<br>` with something else it works.

what mistake i am doing?

Comment: Most likely the `<br>` you are trying to replace, isn’t an actual `<br>` to begin with. (`nl2br` for example produces `<br />` by default.)

Comment: `var_dump($content)`. I suspect your `<br>` string might not be exactly that, maybe `<br/>`

Comment: most likely your $content has <br> saved as "&lt;br&gt;" - so you have to replace that

Comment: @ Brett Gregson, var_dump string(150) "A useful <br> ....."

Comment: @matiit nope, i have checked it display <br>

Comment: @nas are you viewing the page source or in the chrome dev tools? Because chrome might modify the markup

Comment: @BrettGregson I just added htmlspecialchars_decode and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I added this line before the `str_replace`. Then it worked

```
$content = htmlspecialchars_decode($content);
```